# Most efficient way to create a list of dictionaries in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose I have a list of objects and for each of these objects I want to create a dictionary and put all the dictionaries I generated in a list.

What I am doing is the following:

```
def f(x):
    some function f that returns a dictionary given x

list_of_dict = []

xlist = [x1, x2, ..., xN]

for x in xlist:
    list_of_dict.append(f(x))
```

I am wondering whether there is a more efficient (faster) way to create a list of dictionaries than the one I am proposing.

Thank you.

Comment: Faster to type in, or faster in execution? Did you time your function? Did it take a perceptually long time? For how many items?

Comment: Faster in execution. The xlist contains around 2,000,000 elements, and on top of making the function f more efficient I am wondering whether I can make the list creation faster.

Comment: The `append` loop can be replaced with `list_of_dict = [f(x) for x in xlist]` but you'll have to time it to see if it's any faster. Without seeing what `f(x)` does, we cannot reasonably recommend anything. Perhaps cache the result, if you get lots of repeats.

Comment: Thank you. The xlist is a list of links, and the function f request and parse an html page with beautifulSoup from a link and create two lists of strings, and then zips them together as a dictionary.

Comment: `map` is usually one of the faster methods to apply a function to each element of a list. So you would do: `list_of_dict=map(f(x) for x in xlist)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Since you are dealing with HTTP requests (which is not obvious from your question), the rest of the answer is irrelevant: communications will dominate the computations by a sheer margin.** I'll leave the answer here, anyway.

---

The original approach seems to be the slowest:

```
In [20]: %%timeit 
    ...: list_of_dict = [] 
    ...: for x in xlist: 
    ...:   list_of_dict.append(f(x)) 
    ...:                                                                        
13.5 µs ± 39.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Mapping is the best way to go:

```
In [21]: %timeit list(map(f,xlist))                                             
8.45 µs ± 17 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

List comprehension is somewhere in the middle:

```
In [22]: %timeit [f(x) for x in xlist]                                          
10.2 µs ± 22.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```